# execute bash on local machine to do work on remote?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, remote-access

I am thinking about writing an automated script that connects to a server (ssh), copies files from it. execute a script on the server and disconnect.

1. Is it possible to have a script execute code (like code to execute the remote script) from the local machine? i never tried it nor know how to do it.
2. I understand how to use scp for the most part so copying is not a problem
3. After doing 1 i would like to know how to wait for the remote script to finish and maybe once in a while execute the script but disconnect and leave the script running on the server. How do i do that? (should this be in a separate question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A1) To execute a command on a remote server:

`ssh server "/usr/local/sbin/command"`

Using this method, the ssh session will wait for foreground processes to exit.

A3) To execute a background process on the remote server run:

`ssh server "nohup /usr/local/sbin/command &"`

Comment: i dont understand the ssh server. How does it know what the connection info is and which ssh server i am referring too?

Comment: You specify it.  My command is an example.  Replace "server" with a hostname or IP.

Comment: Hey is there a way to do two bash commands in a single line? i doubt ; would work and i have auth keys setup so i dont need to login each time but i am curious.

Comment: ssh server "command1 ; command2"

Answer (score 0):

1. not in a "normal" setup, but possible if you run a grid or a cluster engine. Just copy over a script and execute it
2. to leave the script running just daemonize (run in background with stdin and out redireced to /dev/null) i.e.

   ssh remotehost "command > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &"

if you want to wait but do other stuff then use wait like with local processes

```
ssh firsthost command &
ssh secondhost othercommand &
...

wait
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case might be useful to change your algoritm:

> ...connects to a server (ssh), copies files from it. execute a script on the server and disconnect.

as follows:
connects to a server (ssh), copies files from it, disconnect, background script execution starts.

To have goal here, should be nice to create separated user for copy purposes:

```
#useradd -p xxxx -d /home/username username
```

next, make some changes in this user's `.bash_logout` file:

```
if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
  nohup /usr/local/bin/command &
fi
```

Proceeding this, generate ssh keys for newbie and configure remote login options the way you prefer.

Now each time copying process e.g. `scp user@host:/directory/SourceFile TargetFile` have been done, background task `/usr/local/bin/command` should be started at remote box.

Comment: "$SHLVL" - subshell counter;

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds rather simple (and as others have said is straightforward to implement). Off the top of my head, something like:

```
# with a file named after each node:
SERVERS=`ls /etc/cluster/members`
THIS_NODE=`uname -n`

REMOTE_NAME="/var/cluster/incoming/${THIS_NODE}_$$"

for (i in ${SERVERS}); do
    scp $1 ${i}:${REMOTE_NAME}
    ssh ${i} "bash ${REMOTE_NAME}"
done
```

However, when you get into the details of what might be ivolved and working with more than just a couple of servers, the problem starts to get very complicated, very quickly.

You might want to have a look at [nrpe](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/1_0/addons.html) with Nagios for stuff which gets run regularly, or Canonical's [Landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/landscape) for running ad-hoc stuff on lots of servers (one of the main functions of this is for deploying patches - but it can be used for all sorts of things - and across all sorts of OS).

HTH

C.